# Turn color image into a false color image aka simple (1D) LUT in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, colormap

For a small camera program I need to convert a JPG taken by the RPi camera (RPi3) into a false color image. I want to map every grey value of a color picture to a specific new color value and save the picture as JPEG.

I have the LUT exported in all formats from Photoshop, but a 256x1 png file is supposed to make it easier. I tried to use that (256x1, 8 Bit, PNG, horizontal with the leftmost pixel for the darkest values). My source pictures are 1296x972px, JPEG, 8 Bit.
I tried using `pillow` and `matplotlib`.

The closest I've come to get anything working is the following code.

```py
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

image = Image.open('testbild.jpg')
image = image.convert("L")

# Ensure the image has 3 channels.
image = image.convert('RGB')

# Open the LUT image and convert it to a NumPy array.
lut_image = Image.open('LUT.png')
lut_array = np.array(lut_image)

# Extract the pixel values from the array and flatten them.
lut = lut_array.flatten()

# Apply the LUT to the image.
image = image.point(lut)

image.save('output.jpg')
```

This gives me a blue-ish output, when my LUT is more purple.

This is the LUT.

[[image: LUT]]

The process should be as simple as possible, so I get the result as fast as possible.
The rest of the program is working; I'm just pulling my hair over this part.
I tried all methods that are reported to work, including matplotlibs color maps.
I can get that to work with its own cmaps. It looks good, but it's slow and I can't get my own cmap in.

This is my first program and I'm normally a photographer, so this might be the main problem.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you flatten your LUT in the wrong way, PIL want it like this

```
[r0, r1, ..., r255, g0, g1, ..., g255, b0, b1, ..., b255]
```

while you obtained

```
[r0, g0, b0, r1, g1, b1, ..., r255, g255, b255]
```

because when you read and "array" the LUT, the array has shape `(1, 256, 3)`, that is 1 row, 256 columns, and 3 bytes per pixel,  and flattening collapse the last dimension first.

We want to remove the first dimension, this can be done using `.reshape(-1, 3)` where -1 means collapse all the dimensions that are not explicitly mentioned, so that the array has shape `(256,3)`.

Next we want to transpose the array, using `.T`, and now it has shape `(3, 256).

Finally we can flatten the array and have the LUT in the correct format.

Note that these operations (image to array, reshaping, transposition and flattening) have been chained in my code.

Here it is the code

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('Figure_4.png')
lut = np.array(Image.open('LUT.png')).reshape(-1,3).T.flatten()
img = img.convert('L') ; img = img.convert('RGB')
img.save('Gray.png')
img = img.point(lut)
img.save('Converted.png')
```

and here the original image, the gray scale image and the converted image

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that did the trick! Processing speed isn't terrible but I'm wondering if I could recognizably speed it up if I would do the reading, converting and flattening of the LUT in a seperate code just once. I would print the content of "lut" and use the result directly to convert the image since I only have to use one LUT in the code. I want to show the picture instantly after taking it, this is why less time is better, even if it's a small amount. Do you think this would help? Thanks again!

Comment: @RomanHoltwick On my PC, executing the line `np.array(Image.open('LUT.png')).reshape(-1,3).T.flatten()` takes, on the mean of many executions, 131 μs, so yes, caching the result is however beneficial but, if it's going to complicate the code...

Comment: Well, I'm on a Raspberry Pi 3 and the program should show the finished picture as fast as possible after taking it. That's why I'm thinking about using optimizations like hardcoding the effect and not saving the image (on the SD) between taking and modifying it. But creating the LUT only took the RPi 2.5ms on average, so this might indeed not be the best place to save time, especially if I want to refine the LUT in the future.

Comment: @RomanHoltwick If you've got another problem, the correct course of action is to ask another question.

Comment: Yes, that and the problem I thought existed, didn't exist. I already deleted the comment. I'll leave it here for anyone having this problem: If you save the PNG in Photoshop, you can't have the option "smaller file" ticked. I got an error that says it can't reshape 256 values.